# Why my code work fine on chrome but not firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a split-flap. It works fine in Chrome, but in firefox, during the second rotation period, it is not smooth as in chrome. How can I fix it?

```js
let baseDiv, lowerDiv, middleDiv, upperDiv;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
  baseDiv = document.getElementById("base");
  lowerDiv = document.getElementById("lower");
  middleDiv = document.getElementById("middle");
  upperDiv = document.getElementById("upper");
});
let backward = () => {
  lowerDiv.classList.add("rotate0to90");
}
let forward = () => {
  upperDiv.classList.add("rotate0to_90");
}

let upperHandler = () => {
  upperDiv.classList.replace("zIndex4", "zIndex2");
 middleDiv.innerHTML=baseDiv.innerHTML;
  middleDiv.className = "lowerHalfCard-after zIndex4 rotate90to0 transform0to90"
}
let lowerHandler = () => {
  lowerDiv.classList.replace("zIndex4", "zIndex2");
 middleDiv.innerHTML=baseDiv.innerHTML;
  middleDiv.className = "upperHalfCard-after zIndex4 rotate_90to0 transform0to_90";
}
let middleHandler = () => {
  upperDiv.innerHTML=baseDiv.innerHTML;
  lowerDiv.innerHTML=baseDiv.innerHTML;
  upperDiv.className = "upperHalfCard-after zIndex4";
  lowerDiv.className = "lowerHalfCard-after zIndex2";
  middleDiv.className = "hide";
}
```

```css
.fullCard,
.lowerHalfCard,
.upperHalfCard,
.fullCard-after,
.lowerHalfCard-after,
.upperHalfCard-after {
  background-color: inherit;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fullCard-after::after,
.upperHalfCard-after::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
}

.lowerHalfCard-after::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
}

.lowerHalfCard,
.lowerHalfCard-after {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.upperHalfCard,
.upperHalfCard-after {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0% 50%);
}

.splitFlap {
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.rotate0to90 {
  animation-name: r0to90;
}

.rotate90to0 {
  animation-name: r90to0;
}

.rotate0to_90 {
  animation-name: r0to_90;
}

.rotate_90to0 {
  animation-name: r_90to0;
}

.rotate0to90,
.rotate90to0,
.rotate0to_90,
.rotate_90to0 {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes r0to90 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes r90to0 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes r0to_90 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes r_90to0 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

.transform0to_90 {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.transform0to90 {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

.zIndex2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.zIndex4 {
  z-index: 4;
}

.zIndex10 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue
}

.green {
  background-color: green
}

.red {
  background-color: red
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange
}
```

```html
<div class="splitFlap">
  <div id="base" class="fullCard-after zIndex2">
    <img src="img/1_100.png">
  </div>
  <div class="upperHalfCard-after zIndex4" id="upper" onAnimationEnd="upperHandler()">
    <img src="img/0_100.png">
  </div>
  <div id="middle" class="hide" onAnimationEnd="middleHandler()">
  </div>
  <div class="lowerHalfCard-after zIndex2" id="lower" onAnimationEnd="lowerHandler()">
    <img src="img/0_100.png">
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <button onClick="forward()">
              +
            </button>
  <button onClick="backward()">
             -
            </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing native JS and jQuery like that?

Comment: Do you mean mixing native JS and jQuery will cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound churlish. And, no, probably not the issue, But it's clear that you understand native JS so why use `html()` instead of `innerHTML`. You can throw away jQuery altogether if that's all you're using it for.

Comment: Actually, I don't know mxing native JS and jQuery is not good practice, so I just want to confirm the fact.

Comment: It's mainly just confusing when you jump back and forth between the two styles.

Comment: It's not _bad_ per se, but jQuery was developed in 2006 to cover a lot of JS missing pieces. There's been a lot of JS development in the last 16 years. So while jQuery is still relevant for millions of sites around the world to keep them working, it's slightly less relevant now. Not irrelevant. Just slightly less. But modern JS/CSS can do everything that jQuery can do now.

Comment: I have updated the code. It is pure native JS, unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm note clear what I should be looking at. The snippet gives a JS error when clicking the Set Hinge.

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the "Set Hinge" button.

Comment: I'm still not sure what I should be looking at. Without the images there it's difficult to see what (if anything) is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I have made it work properly by adding the following CSS attribute to the `splitFlap` class

`transform-style: preserve-3d;`

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-moz-` extension before all your transitions in CSS. That will make sure Mozilla *"understands"* it.

Example:

```css
@keyframes r_90to0 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck, it is not working as I expected.

Comment: These extensions are deprecated.

Comment: If you define prefixes like `-moz, -webkit,...` then define them **before** the actual unprefixed property. Secondly, you don't need this prefix for transform, every browser understands this now.

Comment: I would think that the -moz- would work, but apparently not